# Where do trashed Travellers go?

Tags: dominion, dominion-adventures

In Dominion Adventures, when you trash one of the Traveller cards, where does that Traveller go?

The rules seems to imply the Trash pile.

However, since there are only 5 of each pile, I was wondering if there was some specific rules for cards that weren't in Supply like Travellers and Spoils.

Answer (score 3):

If you trash it, then it goes to the trash pile like a normal card.

Same for Spoils and Ruins.

If you exchange a traveler, then it goes back to the original pile.

Comment: As a side note, this means that you *can* gain upgraded cards with Rogue or Graverobber, from Dark Ages.